# writeToFile: returning correct path, but no file?

Tags: nsdata, nsurl, writetofile, cgimageref, nsbitmapimagerep

I have this code to make a PNG out of NSData I have for an NSImage, but no file is created in the Downloads folder?

```
- (IBAction)saveToDownloadsFolder:(id)sender {

    NSInteger selected = [tvContent selectedRow];
    ImageCell *selectedRow = [tvContent viewAtColumn:0 row:selected makeIfNecessary:YES];

    NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDownloadsDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

    CGImageRef CGImage = [selectedRow.item.image CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:nil hints:nil];
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:CGImage] autorelease];
    NSDictionary* imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
    NSData *data = [rep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties:imageProps];
    [data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Copyfeed-Image.png"]] atomically:YES];


    NSLog(@"URL %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Copyfeed-Image.png"]]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to be:

```
[data writeToURL:[documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Copyfeed-Image.png"] atomically:YES];
```

Because I was trying to write to a path, but was returning a URL, you can only write to path it seems if you first create a file there.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.